ADF API call response conversion from JSON to CSV
I'm using an ADF copy activity to copy data from an API (HTTP linked service) to a CSV file in a Blob Storage.
The response from the API looks like this :
{"results":"Customer Name,Cloud Account Name,Product Name,SKU Name,Term And Billing Cycle,Subscription ID,Domain Name,Price book,Seller Cost (EUR),Customer Cost (EUR),Margin (EUR),Usage Quantity,Unit,Region,Seat Count,Subscription StartDate,Subscription EndDate,Charge StartDate,Charge EndDate,Invoice Number,Customer Company\n\"TEST COMPANY\",\"abcd\",\"Test\",\"Test\",\"Test\",\"abcd\",\"Test\",\"\",0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,\"Test\",\"\",1,2024-01-01,2024-01-01,2024-01-01,2024-01-01,\"Test\",\"TEST COMPANY\",\"abcd\",\"Test\",\"Test\",\"Test\",\"abcd\",\"Test\",\"\",0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,0.0000000000000,\"Test\",\"\",1,2024-01-01,2024-01-01,2024-01-01,2024-01-01,\"Test\"","resultCount":"24"}

I'm trying to extract data from the "results" object, but CSV data is written in string. How can I extract CSV string data into a CSV file in a blob storage ?
I tried to copy HTTP response as JSON format to JSON file in a blob storage and then to copy JSON file into a CSV file thanks to a complex mapping (using "results" as collection reference), but CSV file was written in a one line way and was unreadable from ADF (to copy CSV file to SQL table for example).

You need to read the results' value as an intermediate step.

Thank you Ryan, how can I do that ? API Response is too long to use a Web Activity (error : The length of execution output is over limit : arroud 4 MB currently). So I have to use a copy activity). What should be the intermediate step ?

Issue may be with your Json format, that may be the reason to get your CSV file was written in a one-line way. Modify your API response that means Json into below format:
{
  "results": [
    {
      "Customer Name": "TEST COMPANY",
      "Cloud Account Name": "abcd",
      "Product Name": "Test",
      "SKU Name": "Test",
      "Term And Billing Cycle": "Test",
      "Subscription ID": "abcd",
      "Domain Name": "Test",
      "Price book": "",
      "Seller Cost (EUR)": 0.0,
      "Customer Cost (EUR)": 0.0,
      "Margin (EUR)": 0.0,
      "Usage Quantity": 0.0,
      "Unit": "Test",
      "Region": "",
      "Seat Count": 1,
      "Subscription StartDate": "2024-01-01",
      "Subscription EndDate": "2024-01-01",
      "Charge StartDate": "2024-01-01",
      "Charge EndDate": "2024-01-01",
      "Invoice Number": "Test",
      "Customer Company": "TEST COMPANY"
    },
    {
      "Customer Name": "abcd",
      "Cloud Account Name": "Test",
      "Product Name": "Test",
      "SKU Name": "abcd",
      "Term And Billing Cycle": "Test",
      "Subscription ID": "",
      "Domain Name": "0.0",
      "Price book": "0.0",
      "Seller Cost (EUR)": 0.0,
      "Customer Cost (EUR)": 0.0,
      "Margin (EUR)": 0.0,
      "Usage Quantity": 0.0,
      "Unit": "Test",
      "Region": "",
      "Seat Count": 1,
      "Subscription StartDate": "2024-01-01",
      "Subscription EndDate": "2024-01-01",
      "Charge StartDate": "2024-01-01",
      "Charge EndDate": "2024-01-01",
      "Invoice Number": "Test"
    }
  ],
  "resultCount": 24
}

After Json modification you can use copy activity to copy Json into csv file as follows:
Create Json dataset with above Json file provide it as source provide csv dataset for sink, go to mapping enable Advanced editor  and provide $['results'] as Collection reference, then you will get the columns as follows:

Debug the pipeline after successful pipeline debug you will get the csv file as shown below:
Results



Customer Name
Cloud Account Name
Product Name
SKU Name
Term And Billing Cycle
Subscription ID
Domain Name
Price book
Seller Cost (EUR)
Customer Cost (EUR)
Margin (EUR)
Usage Quantity
Unit
Region
Seat Count
Subscription StartDate
Subscription EndDate
Charge StartDate
Charge EndDate
Invoice Number
Customer Company




TEST COMPANY
abcd
Test
Test
Test
abcd
Test

0
0
0
0
Test

1
2024-01-01
2024-01-01
2024-01-01
2024-01-01
Test
TEST COMPANY


abcd
Test
Test
abcd
Test



0.0
0.0
0
0
Test

1
2024-01-01
2024-01-01
2024-01-01
2024-01-01
Test





Thank you for your answer, but I can't modify the API, that's a third-party API.
